# Unable to boot - safe mode stops after crcdisk.sys

Tags: windows, ubuntu, hard-drive

My windows systems hangs at boot time. If I run it using safe mode it stops/hangs after crcdisk.sys

How do I fix this? What is causing the problem?

My priority right now is to copy the data to another drive/system. My windows was/is running on single C drive.

Can I install Ubuntu without losing C drive data? So that I can login into Ubuntu and transfer data to another drive. And, then may be reinstal/format windows OS again

Comment: Waaaaaaait until crcdisk.sys finishes. It will finish

Comment: Yea. That seems to be one solution available on net as well. The problem started after abrupt power outage.

Comment: @hek2mgl It got past the safe mode after 15min. But, again it gets stuck while booting. (stuck and windows green bar screen)

Comment: have you mounted any usb or fire wire disks? or usb sticks? try to unplug them and boot again

Comment: Nothing attached.

Answer (score 0):

**Do Not** continue using the drive until you are sure that it is healthy, that is to say, you should really be careful about what you attempt to do with the drive from this point forward. The longer you use a failing drive the worse and more unreliable it becomes, hopefully you are already aware of that, but just thought I would mention it if you did not.

With that said, you may be able to boot to a Linux/Knoppix LIVE CD and see if you can get any files off the drive that way.  The drive should automatically mount but if you are not sure you can open up a command prompt and run a `fdisk -l` to see what drives Linux thinks is mounted.

Once you have secured your files, it may not be a bad idea also to test the health of the drive with a tool like [Drive Fitness Test](http://www.hgst.com/support/downloads/#DFT) or another disk utility to ensure that there isn't something wrong with the disk.